# Need to call jquery from mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to jQuery and was looking for a way to show/hide partial views in MVC 4. I found a very good example in the link bellow, and copied part of the code here, but it is dependent on the button click event. What I need is to call the function directly by code in the view, and although I dont know how to rewrite it for this purpose I believe this is how it would  be called from the view razor code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">Foo("#div1")</script>
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1743071.aspx/1

```
<style type="text/css">
.inv
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.vis
{
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<div class="inv" id="div1">
    <h2>Div 1</h2>
    <p>
        Hidden at start
    </p>
    <button class="showhide">Hide this div again</button>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".showhide").click(function () {
            $("#div1").toggleClass("vis");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below, the `Foo` method will get called when the document is ready so it does not need to be triggered with a click. It will be passed in the id of the `<div>`.

If you want to conditionally call 'Foo' based on a value in the ViewBag, you simply prevent the view from rendering the JS code that makes the call:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.SomeBooleanProperty = true;
```

View:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function Foo(divId)
   {
      $(divId).toggleClass("vis");
   }    

 @if(ViewBag.SomeBooleanProperty)
 {
        $(function () {
            Foo("#div1");
        });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to call the function as show bellow but it gives: JavaScript runtime error: 'Foo' is undefined    <script type="text/javascript">Foo("div1")</script>

Comment: I figured out what you said about the function be called when the document is ready, but is there anyway to only call it based on, for example a ViewBag value?

Comment: @BenJunior Code has been updated so it is only called if the value in the ViewBag is true.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. (I just moved the @if outside the script tags.)